# Xamarin Document Scanning (device camera only) with UWP or Universal Windows Platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I need to add Document Scanning in Xamarin on UWP.
But most of the third party tools work on Android and iOS.
Is there any third party for document scanning support UWP.

Or any open source which can provide this functionality.

there is any solution related or near to it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use camera to scan the document, (not print scanner ) right ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. (Tablet or Mobile)

Comment: Please check this [blog](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/02/08/optical-character-recognition-ocr-for-windows-10/), you could use camera to capture image and use ocr engine to convert to document.

Comment: I tried to implement this but this is quite different from scanning app. But I think this will be my last option if nothing I got.